# Different languages in MessageBox class in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have added new languages for the Message box window for example in spanish:

In the statics area :

```
NO    : {text: 'No',     itemId: 'no'},
SI      : {text: 'Si',    itemId: 'si', ui: 'action'},
```

and later:

```
SINO:[
    {text: 'No',  itemId: 'no'},
    {text: 'Si', itemId: 'si', ui: 'action'}
],
```

And the translations appears in the message window but doesn´t work correctly the actions, only works in english (default language in Sencha framework)

How am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution... when we add translations to the dialog with, for example, yes or not, or ok and cancel it is not necessary to modify the itemId, only the text, but NOW I have problems with the buttons of the dialog in russian, It appears "???" and " ?? " and doesn´t recognize the language, any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You should only translate the text, not the name of the constants.

```
NO : {text: 'No', itemId: 'no'}, 
YES : {text: 'Si', itemId: 'si', ui: 'action'},


YESNO:[ 
    {text: 'No', itemId: 'no'}, 
    {text: 'Si', itemId: 'si', ui: 'action'}
],
```

Comment: I don´t want to translate the current language, I need to add new languages, for example, English, spanish, german and so on..